# Differential equation of rate of substance!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The rate of which certain substance dissolves in water is proportional at the product of the amount undissolved and the difference between $c_1-c_2$ where $c_1$ is the concentration of the saturated solution and $c_2$ is the concentration of the actual solution! If saturated $50gm$ of water will dissolve $20gm$ of the substance! If $10gm$ of the substance is placed in the $50gm$ of water then half of the substance will dissolve within 90 minutes! How much will dissolve in $3$ hours!

I have tried to solve this but no idea how to tackle this!

My attempt is below

$$\frac{dx}{dt} \alpha (c_1-c_2)$$

I try to introduce a proportionality constant, $k$  to the differential equation

Can someone hint me? And provide the right way to think of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call x the amount of undissolved substance. Then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ gives you the rate at which the substance dissolves. This rate is proportional with the product of the amount of undissolved substance $x$ and $(c_1 -c_2)$

Hence, $$\frac{dx}{dt} = kx(c_1-c_2)$$

for some number $k \in \mathbb{R}$

Equivalently: $$\frac{dx}{x} = k(c_1-c_2)dt \iff \ln|x| = k(c_1-c_2)t + C $$

$$\Rightarrow x(t) = Ce^{k(c_1-c_2)t}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is it that $c_1=\frac{20}{50}$  and$ c_2=\frac{10}{50}$?

Comment: I didn't work it out to that point. But those seem reasonable answers.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the moment I saw this question I was deciding which is the right differential equation.

Comment: Thanks bro! Your guide is much appreciated!